# Unity2D when player inside of particle system [help]

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I want to trigger an event if the player is in Particle Effect
[Smoke particle effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBbn1.png)
So in this case, I have a smoke bomb that can collide with the Ground layer, when I try to collide the particle with the player and use this OnParticleCollision(GameObject obj) thing, but the player is pushing the particles and I don't want that. I only want this when the player touches the particle but does not push it

What i tried =
`OnParticleCollision() OnTriggerEnter2D() OnTriggerStay2D() Raycast2D`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what you are looking for is the [Triggers Module](https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.3/Documentation/Manual/PartSysTriggersModule.html) in the particle system. You can also set the [Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.3/Documentation/Manual/PartSysCollisionModule.html) that the particles collide with to disable collision with the player.

Comment: thanks for the reply and this is what i need, actually i tried this function but it seems i made a mistake in some part. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could help, If your problem is solved please mark my answer as the solution :)